# ViewController custom property

Tags: objective-c, properties

Trying to set a custom property(value) for a ViewController( e.g.- FirstViewController).

FirstViewController.h

```
//..
int value;
}
@property (assign) int value;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
@synthesize value;
-(void)showValue{
    self.value = 3;
    NSLog(@"%d", self.value);
}
```

Here works fine, but when I want to change the value of this variable (value) from another ViewController (ZeroViewController) nothing happens, and in viewDidLoad method of FirstViewController NSLog(@"%d", self.value) i get value == 0; Look the way how I do it.

ZeroViewController.h

```
FirstViewController* firstViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) FirstViewController* firstViewController;
```

ZeroViewController.m

```
FirstViewController *aFirstView = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
self.firstViewController = aFirstView;
[aFirstView release];
firstViewController.value = 1;
NSLog(@" %d", firstViewController.value);
```

FirstViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 NSLog(@"%d", self.value);
}
```

As I suppose here should be "1", but console shows 0.

I think, that happens because I initialize my FirstViewController in ZeroViewController, and when FirstViewController becomes active it initializes again and all values annul. Or maybe I am wrong.

For what I am doing this: I have 10 buttons in a ZeroViewController. I want FirstViewController to change its value (self.value) When I press any button.

E.G.

> > firstViewController.value = 123;

If it is possible to help, please, do so.

Thanks!

http://narod.ru/disk/571946001/TestingValues.zip.html

The project.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how your firstViewController property is setup.  It it does not retain aFirstView, you'd be releasing it prematurely which could lead to some weird results (although I'd expect a bad access exception in this case.)

Comment: http://narod.ru/disk/571946001/TestingValues.zip.html Here is the source code. with some modifications I've made expecting to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I've assigned my view's property in the method when I change the views.